# Hide Home Indicator for iPhone X in Xamarin.Forms page

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to hide the home indicator in a Xamarin.Forms application? Looks like i need to get root UIViewControler of Forms application and somehow override [PrefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiviewcontroller.prefershomeindicatorautohidden) to return true. But i don't have access to that root UIViewControler...

Do you have any ideas how to hide Home Indicator in Xamarin.Forms app?

Comment: I'd be *very* careful about hiding the home indicator. What's your use case?

Comment: Please answer the above question so we can help

Comment: I have an app with the tv player and i want to hide home Indicator when user watches player on fullscreen, so user can get rid of annoying bar. I just want to have an ability to hide indicator from iPhone X on certain pages.

Comment: I've managed to hide home indicator in my native app by overriding prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden and calling setNeedsUpdateOfHomeIndicatorAutoHidden in viewDidAppear inside my ViewContoller, and that works for me. Now i just want to mimic that behaviour into my XF app, but i have hard times with overriding PrefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden as i cannot access it. 

Now im trying to override this property via reflection, but without success so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this in the constructor of my `Xamarin.Forms.Page` after `InitializeComponent()`:

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;
// ...

if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS &&  
    DeviceInfo.Version.Major > 11)
{
    On<iOS>().SetPrefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden(true);
}
```

Based on [this source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/page-home-indicator).

My use case was to create clean screenshots in the iOS simulator for the App Store.

Comment: Yes community already added this feature into Xamarin Forms :) If you remove condition about DeviceType.Virtual  i'll accept your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply create a custom renderer and override this property.

Something like this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyPage), typeof(HomeIndicatorRenderer))]
namespace MyApp
{ 
    public class HomeIndicatorRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public override bool PrefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden => true;

        public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
            SetNeedsUpdateOfHomeIndicatorAutoHidden();
        }
    }
}
```

You should probably mix in a check if the version is iOS 11 or higher somewhere.

But as already pointed out, you probably want to be careful with this. And I think the Apple documentation even states that this setting can be ignored by the OS at will.

Comment: Looks good, dosn't work. This solution is similar to that https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/127631/hide-home-indicator-in-xamarin-forms, but without the NavigationRenderer part

Comment: Looking at the comments on your question, this does work when doing it in Swift/Obj-C. I don't quite get what you mean with "Now im trying to override this property via reflection, but without success so far". It seems you can override it as per my code above?

Comment: With reflection i wanted to override PrefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden property without creating subclass of UIViewController, but your idea of creating CustomPageRenderer (that inherits from UIViewController) is a lot easier. 

Your solution with rednerer doesn't work, because root UIViewConroler from Xamarin.Forms doesn't override ChildViewControllerForHomeIndicatorAutoHidden. Here is PR with that change https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/1515, but is declined, i will try resurrect it

Comment: Ah, I see. I think the PR was shot down because of the lack of an issue to discuss this. So, please open an issue proposing adding this. I might be able to do that for you :)

Comment: And the reason why my native code is working, and Forms isn't, is because in native implementation im changing whole controller with method: [rootContoller presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:NIL] and inside XF im only adding child to root controller, and root controller doesn't give a sh#t about children :)

Comment: Great! I'll see if I can have a quick look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Issue closed, feature will be available in 4.0